# Why did this work with Visual C++, but not with gcc?

Tags: c++, string, gcc

I've been working on a senior project for the last several months now, and a major sticking point in our team's development process has been dealing wtih rifts between Visual-C++ and gcc. (Yes, I know we all should have had the same development environment.) Things are about finished up at this point, but I ran into a moderate bug just today that had me wondering whether Visual-C++ is easier on newbies (like me) by design.

In one of my headers, there is a function that relies on `strtok` to chop up a string, do some comparisons and return a string with a similar format. It works a little something like the following:

```
int main()  
{  
    string a, b, c;  
    //Do stuff with a and b.  
    c = get_string(a,b);  
}   


string get_string(string a, string b)  
{  
    const char * a_ch, b_ch;
    a_ch = strtok(a.c_str(),",");  
    b_ch = strtok(b.c_str(),",");  
}
```

`strtok` is infamous for being great at tokenizing, but equally great at destroying the original string to be tokenized. Thus, when I compiled this with gcc and tried to do anything with `a` or `b`, I got unexpected behavior, since the separator used was completely removed in the string. Here's an example in case I'm unclear; if I set `a = "Jim,Bob,Mary"` and `b="Grace,Soo,Hyun"`, they would be defined as `a="JimBobMary"` and `b="GraceSooHyun"` instead of staying the same like I wanted.

However, when I compiled this under Visual C++, I got back the original strings and the program executed fine.

I tried dynamically allocating memory to the strings and copying them the "standard" way, but the only way that worked was using `malloc()` and `free()`, which I hear is discouraged in C++. While I'm curious about that, the real question I have is this: Why did the program work when compiled in VC++, but not with gcc?

(This is one of many conflicts that I experienced while trying to make the code cross-platform.)

Thanks in advance!

-Carlos Nunez

Comment: I don't see a problem with using `malloc` or `free` in C++, as long as you check for errors.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile.  strtok takes a char* as the first argument and c_str() returns const char*.  Regardless it may be better to use C++ functions that work on std::strings to do the tokenizing in this case.  find_first_of and substr come to mind.

Comment: @Dietrich There isn't, really, but usually people use `new` and `delete` instead

Comment: @Dan That's hardly the only problem; `b_ch` is also a `char` instead of a `char*`, and `get_string()` doesn't return anything. I think he came up with this from memory rather than copying it from the actual source

Comment: strtok() in each case will return the first token from each string - I have no idea how could it remove all the delimiters from the whole string as shown in your example. Secondly msdn notes as well that the first parameter is modified as well, maybe different versions? The strtok() replaces the delimiter with NULL in the original string so it does not 'remove' the delimiter from the original string, it replaces it with NULL. If you inspect memory you can still see the string with delimiters replaced by NULL - off course this happen gradually, one delimiter is replaced by NULL per each call.

Comment: What version of gcc? http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtok.3.html#BUGS

Comment: @Dietrich: See what you said? "As long as you check for errors." Why make things harder on yourself when it's wrapped away in new/delete? This also ignores the fact using `malloc` and casting leads to undefined behavior if the type is not a POD type. Then construct it with placement new you say; well sure. Except now you need a try/catch block to ensure you don't leak if the constructor throws, and now your deletion of that memory is clumsy. All in place of simply using new and delete. So yea, malloc and free are fine if you like doing redundant work that's easy to mess up.

Comment: Of course, why use either when `std::vector` and/or smart pointers exist? :)

Comment: @Carlos: to reduce confusion, post actual code you can compile & run so people aren't left chasing typos.  Passing `somestring.c_str()` to `strtok()` causes an error in MSVC since VC6. Are you casting to get rid of the error?  If so, there should be no surprise that you're getting weird results.

Comment: @Dan Olson: it's a left over from c. "const char*" is auto converted into "char*" just for backward comparability. Usually if you turn the warning level of your compiler unto max you will get warnings but technically the compiler must allow it!

Comment: @Martin York can you cite a reference in the standard?  I've never seen a C++ compiler implicitly cast away const.

Comment: @Martin: I get an error. I think you mean string *literals* can be converted to `char*`.

Comment: @Dan Olson: My mistake, (Thanks to UncleBen) I was thing about string literals (which are char const*) which are auto-converted to (char*) for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I came up with that from memory, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tokens will be automatically replaced by a null-character by function [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/). That is not what you can do with constant data.

To make your code safe and cross-platform consider using [`boost::tokenizer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm).

Comment: I amazed this did not get upvoted before. The current "big" answer does talk at large about the problem and why, but its suggested solution is kind of crappy...

Comment: Didn't know about that, though I shouldn't have been surprised; boost has everything. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And about a year later, I think this is the better approach. Boost is awesome. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of undefined behavior.  You're passing the result of `string::c_str()`, a `const char*`, to strtok, which takes a `char*`.  By modifying the contents of the std::string data, you're invoking undefined behavior (you should be getting warnings for this unless you're casting).

When are you checking the value of a and b?  In get_string, or in main?  get_string is passed copies of a and b, so strtok will most likely not alter the originals in main.  However, it could, as you are invoking undefined behavior.

The "right way" to do this is to use malloc/free or new[]/delete[].  You're using a C function, so you're already guilty of the same crime as you would be using malloc/free.  A relatively elegant yet safe way to approach this is:

```
char *ap = strdup(a.c_str());
const char *a_ch = strtok(ap, ",");
/* do whatever it is you do */
free(ap);
```

Also bear in mind that strtok uses global state, so it won't play well with threads.

Comment: Why `new[]/delete[]` over a much simpler `std::vector`?

Comment: In this case, std::vector wouldn't be much simpler than allocating with strdup() and freeing with free().  I guess std::vector might be a little simpler than new[]/delete[], though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is working because of differences in string implementation. VC++ string implementation must be making copies when you pass them to a function that could potentially modify the string.

Comment: Another hypothesis is that the code optimizer eliminated the `strtok()` call, when it deduced that there was no legal way to observe the result of the call (dead code optimization).

Comment: I would doubt this very much. How is `string.c_str()` to know how it is going to be used?